# Pull range of data into List Box

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I got range of data in which I have 10 columns, and I'd like to pull that data into list box.

Here is my code: - when I run I got compile error .

```
Sub PullDataIntoListBox()

Dim LRow As Long
Dim LCol As Long
Dim MTable
EditData.Show

With Worksheets("MainDataBase")
    LRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LCol = Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    MTable = Range(Cells(5, 1), Cells(LRow, LCol))
End With

With EditData
    .ColumnCount = UBound(MTable, 2)
    .List = MTable

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line was the error and what error code?

Comment: Also, if you're using a UDF, should you not be using Sub UserForm_Initialize() to pull the data in?

Comment: Isn't  `EditData` the form, not the listbox?

Comment: `Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` is looking at the active sheet.  `.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` would look at `MainDataBase` (note the `.` at the start).

Comment: `MTable` should be `Set MTable = ` as it's a range.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook actually I'd try to use MTable as array to make faster my code. I got ten columns to add ListBox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Cyril said.  Use the `Initialize` event so the listbox is populated when the form opens.

As the code is in the form you can refer to the form using the `Me` keyword.

**Using array as a source:**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim LRow As Long, LCol As Long
    Dim MTable As Variant

    With Worksheets("MainDataBase")
        LRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        LCol = .Cells(4, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        MTable = .Range(.Cells(5, 1), .Cells(LRow, LCol))
    End With

    With Me.ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = UBound(MTable, 2)
        .List = MTable
    End With

End Sub
```

Or if you'd prefer to have the code in a normal module you can call it from the *Initialize* event:

In the form:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    PullDataIntoListBox Me.ListBox1

End Sub
```

In a normal module:

```
Public Sub PullDataIntoListBox(lstbx As MSForms.ListBox)

    Dim LRow As Long, LCol As Long
    Dim MTable As Variant

    With Worksheets("MainDataBase")
        LRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        LCol = .Cells(4, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        MTable = .Range(.Cells(5, 1), .Cells(LRow, LCol))
    End With

    With lstbx
        .ColumnCount = UBound(MTable, 2)
        .List = MTable
    End With

End Sub
```

**Using range as a source:**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim LRow As Long, LCol As Long
    Dim MTable As Range

    With Worksheets("MainDataBase")
        LRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        LCol = .Cells(4, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set MTable = .Range(.Cells(5, 1), .Cells(LRow, LCol))
    End With

    With Me.Controls("ListBox1")
        .ColumnCount = MTable.Columns.Count
        .RowSource = "'" & MTable.Parent.Name & "'!" & MTable.Address
    End With

End Sub
```

To open the form and populate the listbox you'd just use `EditData.Show`.

```
Sub SomeOtherProcedure()

    EditData.Show

End Sub
```

**Edit:**
If you want two instances of the same form open but using different values in the listbox you could use code similar to this:

In a normal module add this code:

```
Option Explicit

Public colForms As New Collection

'Accepts a range reference as an argument which is passed to the ListBox control on the form.
'The form reference is then added to the colForms collection.
Sub OpenInstance(ListRange As Range)

    Dim frm As New EditData

    With frm.Controls("ListBox1")
        .ColumnCount = ListRange.Columns.Count
        .RowSource = "'" & ListRange.Parent.Name & "'!" & ListRange.Address
    End With

    colForms.Add frm, CStr(frm.Hwnd)

End Sub

'Starts two new forms, passing a different range to each one.
'Each form in the colForms collection is then displayed.
Sub OpenForms()

    Dim f As Variant

    OpenInstance ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MainDataBase").Range("A1:D16")
    OpenInstance ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("D3:E5")

    For Each f In colForms
        f.Show vbModeless
    Next f

End Sub

'Called when the form closes.
'The form is hidden before removing it from the collection.
Sub CloseForm(Hwnd As String)
    colForms(Hwnd).Hide
    colForms.Remove Hwnd
End Sub
```

In the form add this code:

```
Option Explicit

'Code for capturing forms Hwnd taken from:
'https://colinlegg.wordpress.com/2016/05/06/getting-a-handle-on-userforms-vba/
#If Win64 Then

    Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowA _
        Lib "user32.dll" ( _
        ByVal lpClassName As String, _
        ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr

    Private mlnghWnd As LongPtr

    Public Property Get Hwnd() As LongPtr
        Hwnd = mlnghWnd
    End Property

#Else

    Private Declare Function FindWindowA _
        Lib "user32.dll" ( _
        ByVal lpClassName As String, _
        ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

    Private mlnghWnd As Long

    Public Property Get Hwnd() As Long
        Hwnd = mlnghWnd
    End Property

#End If

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    StorehWnd

End Sub

Private Sub StorehWnd()

    Dim strCaption As String
    Dim strClass As String

    'class name changed in Office 2000
    If Val(Application.Version) >= 9 Then
        strClass = "ThunderDFrame"
    Else
        strClass = "ThunderXFrame"
    End If

    'remember the caption so we can
    'restore it when we're done
    strCaption = Me.Caption

    'give the userform a random
    'unique caption so we can reliably
    'get a handle to its window
    Randomize
    Me.Caption = CStr(Rnd)

    'store the handle so we can use
    'it for the userform's lifetime
    mlnghWnd = FindWindowA(strClass, Me.Caption)

    'set the caption back again
    Me.Caption = strCaption

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    CloseForm CStr(Me.Hwnd)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for all your support, I appreciate it.
But in fact the first code which is similar mine didn't work with me. I got 10 columns in range, may be it cause error. actually I'd like to use my table like array to make much more faster my code.

Comment: I've updated the answer with code for an array.  The only problem you were really having is that you weren't referencing the listbox.  `With EditData` is a reference to the form.  You'd need `With EditData.ListBoxName` and have the listbox populate on the initialize event.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. Code for Array source  is working properly. I did some mistakes when I wrote that code for the first time.
Actually I make right reference for listbox then but I think the problem happen because of 
10 columns, that's why I'd prefer use array,
Everything is ok now. Thanks again!